# Calling two functions in OnPress throws "too many rerenders" error

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a modal which contains a form where a user can update their profile information. Upon submitting the form, I want to update their data in the DB, and also close the modal. I have a handler that does both, which I call onPress in the submit button - but this throws an error `invariant violation- too many re-renders` whenever I try to load the screen. I suspect it's because I'm updating state the wrong way, but I'm not sure why because I'm only calling useState once. My code below:

```
const TeamEditForm = props => {
  const initialState = {
    newTeamName: "",
    modalVisible: false,
  }

  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState(initialState.modalVisible)
  const [newTeamName, setNewTeamName] = useState(initialState.newTeamName)
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState("1")

  const { teamName } = props

  const { user } = useContext(UserContext)
  const { uid } = user

  const toggleModal = () => {
    setModalVisible(!modalVisible)
  }

  const handleNewTeamName = text => {
    setNewTeamName(text)
  }

  const onSubmit = (uid, newTeamName, logo) => {
   updateUser(uid, newTeamName, logo)
   toggleModal() /** This line is what's causing the error, if I remove it code works */
  }



  return (
 <View>
      <Modal
        animationType="slide"
        transparent={false}
        visible={modalVisible}
        supportedOrientations={["landscape"]}
      >
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              flexDirection: "row",
              justifyContent: "flex-start",
              width: "100%",
            }}
            onPress={toggleModal}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, marginLeft: 10 }}>X</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TextInput
            style={[styles.teamNameInput, globalStyles.h1]}
            underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
            placeholder={teamName}
            placeholderTextColor="#000"
            onChangeText={handleNewTeamName}
          />
          <LogoSelector
            style={{ marginVertical: 10 }}
            selected={logo}
            onSelect={setLogo}
          />
          <CustomButton
            title="Submit"
            onPress={onSubmit()}
            size="sm"
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={toggleModal}>
        <Text style={globalStyles.h4}> Edit Team </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

export default TeamEditForm
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you shoud not use onPress like this. Instead use this :

`onPress={() => this.firstFunction(param1) }>`

If you want to update state with onPress you can do it like this :

`onPress={() => this.setState({ submit: !this.state.submit })}`

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses my issue, and I'm not using setState I'm using react hooks.